# Regex get string after string and between white spaces

Tags: java, regex

I'm parsing /var/log/secure looking to check for sudo commands in Linux and need a regex to pull out the user ID that did it.

I have a log entries that looks like this:

```
Nov 13 11:44:41 hostname sudo:     accountName : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/somedir ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chmod 777 /tmp/somedir/
Nov 13 11:44:41 hostname sudo: accountName : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/somedir ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chmod 777 /tmp/somedir/
```

For whatever reason, I run across some log entries where there is a bunch of white space between `sudo:` and `accountname`.

Using a regex, how do I extract the text after `sudo:` followed by any number of blank spaces and before any number of blank spaces followed by `:`

I've been playing with online regex testers and this is as close as I've been able to get:

```
((sudo:)[ \t]+).*?([ \t]+)
```

Note: regex needs to be a valid java regular expression.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue you're having. What's the expected output? Your regex seems fine. I mean, at it's most basic, you can use `sudo:[ \t]+(.*?)[ \t]+:` and your result is in capture group 1

Comment: Use `String regex = "sudo:\\s*(\\w+)";` and use captured group #1

Comment: https://www.regextester.com/  <-- If I run the 1st line through the tester, it returns "sudo:     accountName ".  i'm trying to get just "accountName" returned.

Comment: @user3246693 the first capture group contains what you need.

Comment: Maybe i'm not understanding capture groups.  I thought I just referenced them with {#} at the end of the regex, but this isn't parsing correctly either:  (sudo:[ \t]+).*?([ \t]+\:){1}

Comment: trying https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output out, this returns a list of all groups, and it doesn't list any groups with "accountName" in it?

Comment: @user3246693 Your regex works, just wrap the `.*?` with a capturing group  - `((sudo:)[ \t]+)(.*?)([ \t]+)` and your value will be in `matcher.group(3)`. Not sure you need so many capturing groups though.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `sudo:\\s+([^\\s]+)`. This should match `sudo: accountName`, `sudo:   accountName`, `sudo:account_name`, and so on (if you want to match `sudo:accountName` change the first plus sign `+` for an asterisk `*`). It stops when it finds an space after the account name. Then, it's just a matter of getting the value of `matcher.group(1)` which would be the account name. Like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("sudo:\\s+([^\\s]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Nov 13 11:44:41 hostname sudo:     accountName : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/somedir ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chmod 777 /tmp/somedir/");
matcher.find(); // Keep in mind this assumes all lines will match
System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // accountName
```

Here you have a [working example](https://tio.run/##tVHLTsMwELznK1Y5JSo4jahUkZADAo4tFS1CqC2Sm7iJS2Jb9qYCoX57cPPghsSFgzXe2Vl7tHOgR3opFROH7P26aXilpEY4WJbUyEuiWc4@yIxiWjAdO7/0FxSRaRE7aUmNgRUz@OUAqHpX8hQMUrRwlDyDinLhLVFzkQPVuVlv/bMSoOdKLpglIYGOBnDn8gjhFYRhNJlEkxAKaVDQioGpMxm1GpqmshY4P7MRrFaviUITjCGGxct9EhhZsYxrWz4vH54SLSXa@93jbHY7t@0dF0FaVDKD6XQKAVZqmAjciz@6@D8HrYFT3EK/Z1A9JgNDUlkpXjLPbe1sNmbkrd8sbEe@63fDe6k9LhB4Mo6B37SbJiUTORa2Ho38YeN92jarDpPhP9IzXpcS3/YvwyAley4y74ddfhpkFZE1EmXTxVJ4gzDXslZe6Pfak3M@p6b5Bg)

Side note: You can accomplish the same in a single line with this approach (without regular expressions):

```
"Nov 13 11:44:41 hostname sudo:     accountName : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/somedir ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chmod 777 /tmp/somedir/".split("sudo:")[1].trim().split(" ")[0];
```

Here you have a [working example](https://tio.run/##tZBNT4QwEIbv@ysmnCCrfEQSIsjBqMdFI2yM2XDoQoWutCV0IDGG344F5O7FQzOdZ6bpm@dCBnItWyou5eftNBUNUQoyqvB7B9D254YVoJCgLoNkJXDChJlix0QFpKvUKbfmTYBf1jBBNYQYVgxgJHIA7wY8L/T90PeglgoF4RRUX8pw2SFFIXuByUxDyLL3uEXluBDBy9tj7CjJack63R7Tp9e4kxL1/eH5cLhP9PjMhFPUXJYQBAE4yNvthWNc/THF/yVYAozRUj5kZzKBwGI3Ana3yLIbKiqsdb/fW5u09Esh5bbs0W61V2yEuZplua3ahqFpLLkN6@TltlbPTWsbgIZubq0/jrv5jNP0Aw)